# Javascript doing something strange? works in IE but not firefox?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an element onclick and hide the element when it is clicked but it does nothing?

Why does the hide() function do nothing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(){
  var a = document.getElementById('foo');
  var b = document.createElement("div");
  b.setAttribute('id', 'bar');
  b.setAttribute('onclick', 'hide()');
    a.appendChild(b);
b.innerHTML = 'TEXT CONTENT';
b.onclick = function() { 
    hide();
};
} 

function hide() {
    var x = document.getElementById('foo'); 
  var z = document.getElementById('bar');
  x.removeChild(z);
}
</script>

<div id="foo" onclick="show()">CLICK ME</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 
b.onclick = function() {hide();};

Comment: b.setAttribute('onclick', 'hide()');

I've already added the onclick function?

Comment: some browsers need this and others are ok with just what you had

Answer (score 1):

If this is occurring under IE, then see [Stackoverflow - Why does an onclick property set with setAttribute fail to work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery method to register function it will work in both IE,FF

A sample for u

```
$(b).click(function() {
//call your function like hide() i have made a separate function for cleaner code and re usability 
        });

function hide()
{

}
```