# Key press event is not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, mozilla, keypress

Key press event is not working in Mozilla Firefox. 
I have create a table row dynamically with a text boix in it and that text box has a key press event too.

```
  var el = document.createElement('input');
           el.type = 'text';
           el.name = 'suggest2';
             el.setAttribute("id",str2); 

             el.setAttribute("onkeypress","additemifenter(this.id)"); 
 cell2.appendChild(el);
row.appendChild(cell2);
```

In google chrome the function additemifenter(this.id) is called. But in firefox that function is not getting executed. What is the alternate way to do this in firefox?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the semicolon at the end would help

```
el.setAttribute("onkeypress","additemifenter(this.id);");
```

but

why don't you use the standard event handling model:

```
el.onkeypress = function(event){
// functionality
};
```

or

```
el.addEventListener("keypress",function(event){ 
// functionality
},false);
```

to check the keycode you must use the code:

```
var code = (event.keyCode) ? event.keyCode : event.which;

if(code == 13){

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually that function is calling but the checking is not working. The code for the checking in that function isif(window.event.keyCode==13)
{
 addingsecrow2(id);
}

Comment: FYI, could simplify to `var code = event.keyCode || event.which;`