# How to call the function dynamically in JavaScript for onblur event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Why does an onclick property set with setAttribute fail to work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie)
> [Key press event is not working in mozilla fire fox.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235689/key-press-event-is-not-working-in-mozilla-fire-fox)

```
inp6.setAttribute("onblur","func1("+mb+")");//one way 
inp6.setAttribute("onblur",func1("+mb+"));//2nd waay
```

How to call my customized function `func1(`) when on blur for a element in JavaScript?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235689/key-press-event-is-not-working-in-mozilla-fire-fox