# Firefox event is not defined

Tags: events, mozilla

I call function JS in my HTML like that:

```
     <div style="width:99%;">
       <textarea rows="4"  name="xxx" id="xxx" dojoType="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea"
        onKeyPress="zzz(event);return false;" ><?php echo i18n("textareaEnterText");?></textarea>
     </div>
```

And i have a function JS zzz(event) like that :

```
function zzz(event){
var key = event.keyCode;
if (key == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
   ...
}
```

In Chrome , it's working , but on Mozilla i have an error : " event is not defined"

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6235715/7421571), it could help you.

Comment: Don't working for me ... :(

Comment: It's weird, because I have no problem with the lower case form of `ontkeypress`. Where is exactly your issue? On the definition of the function, on the call of the function, ...?

Comment: Call of the function i think , because if i delete the parameters "event" of my function the error not display... But function don't working

Comment: Could you provide us a full snippet of your code? It is possible that the bug comes from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with all lower case **onkeypress**:

```
<div style="width:99%;">
   <textarea rows="4"  name="xxx" id="xxx" dojoType="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea"
    onkeypress="zzz(event);return false;" ><?php echo i18n("textareaEnterText");?></textarea>
 </div>
```

JavaScript is case sensitive language and all events are lowercase so be careful

Comment: Thanks for your answer but don't working in firefox again ... :(

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of your problem, but you should use: data-dojo-type not dojoType as dojoType is deprecated

Comment: Ok but effectively it's not the answer of my problem