# `onclick` event not called when element clicked with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-events

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie) solution does not work for IE9.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById('unsubref').onclick = function() {unsubcribe();}; 
});
```

and unsubref is:

```
<div id="unsub">
<h1>Click <a id="unsubref">here</a> to unsubscribe from the mailing service</h1>
</div>
```

in Chrome, it works just fine. The function `unsubscribe` is being invoked with alert.

However, in IE9 it does not work!

Comment: Post the code for the `unsubscribe()` function.

Comment: Works in my IE (7-9). Also I don't understand why, while using jQuery, you would want to use attribute-event-handlers or even `getElementById`?

Comment: @Yoshi - how can I use something else instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery I would recommend you using the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method to subscribe to the handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#unsubref').click(unsubcribe); 
});
```

or using an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#unsubref').click(function() {
        alert('unsubscribing ...');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#unsubref').bind("click", function(){ alert(''); });
```

Comment: -1 There is no `bind` method on a DOM Element. Where thinking jQuery maybe?