# Problems with JavaScript in IE

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I have written a code in javascript which creates a `p` attribute dynamically along with a button which will remove the content. The function `removeValue` works fine in Chrome and Firefox but does not work in IE. Also, the `setAttribute('style','')` is not working in IE either. Lastly when I send the values to another page using `window.location` it sends `undefined` instead of the text.

Everything seems to work fine in Firefox and Chrome but I can't get it to work in IE (Currently using IE 7). How can I solve this issue?

The code:

```
function removeValue(ob)
{
    ob.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(ob.parentNode);
}
function throwval(obj)
{
    var sent_id = obj.id;     //get id of the button 
    var v = document.getElementById(sent_id).value;
    var newp = document.createElement("p");     //create a new <p> tag
    var text = document.createTextNode(v);
    var buttonnode= document.createElement('input');
    buttonnode.setAttribute('type','button');
    buttonnode.setAttribute('name','del');
    buttonnode.setAttribute('value','Remove');
    buttonnode.setAttribute('style','background-color: Transparent;width: 125;color: blue;border:0');
    buttonnode.setAttribute('onclick','removeValue(this)');
    newp.appendChild(text);
    newp.appendChild(buttonnode);
    document.getElementById("getselected").appendChild(newp);    //append the new <p> tag in the div    
}
function sendvalues()
{
    var div_val = document.getElementById("getselected");
    if(!div_val.getElementsByTagName("p").length)
    {
        alert("Select a value");
    }
    else
    {
        //get seperate values of the paragraph inside div
        var str="|";
        for (i=0; i < div_val.getElementsByTagName("p").length; i++)
        {
            var paragraphs = div_val.getElementsByTagName("p");
            if(!paragraphs.item(i).textContent)
        {
            var pvalues = paragraphs.item(i).innerText;
        }
        else 
        {
            var pvalues = paragraphs.item(i).textContent;
        }
            //var sendpvalues = "products=" + pvalues;
            // alert(pvalues);

            str = str + pvalues + "|";
            //alert (str);
            //ajaxOb.send(sendpvalues);

        }   
        // alert(str);
        window.location="send_data.php?str="+str;
    }
}
```

Turns out that IE supports '`innerText`' and firefox supports '`textContent`'. I fixed the `undefined` issue by using '`if`' statement. Code updated

Comment: About `window.location` issue, you should set `window.location.href`, since location is an object.

Comment: Strange mix of Dom access. If you want the value of a text field, why do you not access the inputs?

Comment: @uby true but does not matter. Default action is to do the same as setting the href

Comment: 'window.location.href' gives me the same result. I do not have any text fields, just text which i retrieve as search result from another php page @mplungjan

Comment: I see you create input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has an issue with the `setAttribute` function and event handlers. (Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie).) Use the `onclick` property in addition to `setAttribute`.

```
buttonnode.setAttribute('onclick','removeValue(this)');
buttonnode.onclick = function() { removeValue(buttonnode); };
```

Comment: IE7, wow. You realize that most sites are now only supporting 9 and 10, right? Anyway, it probably didn't work because I used `this` incorrectly. I updated the code. Also, you should probably be using a debugger to look at these issue more closely (if you aren't already).

Comment: indeed, I am only using it for testing purposes. This worked. Thank you. I also fixed the `undefined` issue. now only the `style` problem remains

Comment: @GJK: That may be true of the kinds of sites that developers use but is not true at all in general. Huge numbers of sites still have to support IE 8 at least and will do for quite some time. There is still a lot of Windows XP around, for a start, and IE 8 is the last version of IE that will run on XP.

Comment: Also, there's no need for the `setAttribute()` line. The second line using the `onclick` property will work in everything.

Comment: Google dropped support for IE8 last November. When Google does something, that's pretty much a guarantee that it's OK for you to do it.

Comment: I disagree, although that move by Google (who have a vested interest in getting people off IE and onto Chrome) undeniably speeds things along. It really depends on your site's target audience.