# Difference between image.setAttribute and image.src

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between the below two methods

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
1) image.setAttribute('src','mySrc');
2) image.src = 'mySrc';
```

For any html element, is there a difference in setting some attribute in the above ways ? Is there any browser dependability ?

Answer (score 3):

With setAttribute() you can add an attribute even if it doesn't exist.
But it's supported only on major browsers. Ie8 and earlier doesn't
support this function.

[From w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

You should use the attribute when it exists.

**The performance of setAttribute is worse**

I tested 100 image elements.

- Running a function that changes the src it took 2 ms.
- Using setAttribute took 4 ms.

Comment: do you have a source for that quote?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer which one?

Comment: The block that you indented - the formatting is similar to a quotation. Did you not mean to imply that it was one?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer [Here From w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)
At the middle of th page.

Comment: Just did some formatting for you. For your performance testing I recommend creating a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) and getting times of at least a couple hundred ms. Rendering frames ideally takes 16ms so a difference of anything less than that can just depend on when you ran the test.

Answer (score 1):

2nd method can be used only if the attribute is already available where as 1st Method will create it and assign the value in case if it is not available.

For the image.src, both will work as 'src' attribute is available by default.

Comment: For onclick, which method is good ? image.onclick or image.setAttribute('onclick','') ?

Comment: @RaheebM check these links for image.onClick http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie

Comment: Because, onclick is an event unlike src, using inline methods have certain disadvantages as describe in above link.