# How to change a x3dom shape with onClick, when using React?

Tags: html, reactjs, x3d, x3dom

I am trying to use React together with X3DOM. 
I want to be able to click on the red x3dom `<box>` so that it changes its color to blue, when pressed. I have tried using a onClick method in the `<shape>` tag. I was only able to do this by pressing a html `<button>` instead. I have the button also in the code.

This is my index.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isToggleOn: true };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <x3d width='500px' height='300px' >
                <scene>
                    <shape onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <appearance>
                            <material id='color' diffusecolor={this.state.isToggleOn ? '1 0 0' : '0 0 1'}> </material>
                        </appearance>
                        <box></box>
                    </shape>
                </scene>
            </x3d>

            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'BLUE' : 'RED'}
            </button>

        </div>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Toggle />, document.getElementById('toggle'));
```

Can someone give me a solution, or an explanation why this doesn’t work. I would greatly appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Johannes already pointed out, you need to add your event listeners after X3DOM has been initialized. 
If you look closely at https://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/animationInteraction/picking/index.html you will find that they explicitly state:

> **Caveat**: The call of the onclick function is handled by x3dom by
>   directly calling the callback function, since the addEventListener
>   method needed to be overwritten. No page-wide onclick events are
>   thrown, so attaching a listener to this object is only possible **after**.
>   In this case, do not use `$("#myBox").on("click", doSomething(event))`
>   but `$("#myBox").attr("onclick", "doSomething(event)")` instead.
>   Alternatively, wait until the page is fully loaded and the
>   `document.onload` event was fired.

A working example might look like this:

```
var glob = {};
class Toggle {
    ...    
    componentDidMount() {
      glob.handleClick = this.handleClick;
      var k = document.getElementsByTagName('shape')[0];
      k.setAttribute('onclick', 'glob.handleClick()');
    }
```

Please note that I had to introduce a global object in order to get it working, which is probably just a lack of my knowledge of React. You may find a better way.

You can also see it at: https://codepen.io/pgab/pen/gBpEWo

Comment: I tried your code from codepen in my application on localhost. But it doesn’t work for me. Everything except the ability to click on the box works as expected, even the console.log message which shows the onClick method inside the shape tag. Is there any reason why it should not work on localhost?

Comment: No, it should work the same way as on codepen. There is no additional magic. Are using `file:///` or `http://`? Maybe there is a difference between the versions used on codepen and your local? If you could show some code, e.g. as GIST it would be easier to spot an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that X3DOM calls eventHandlers directly.
Quote from the [docu](https://doc.x3dom.org/tutorials/animationInteraction/picking/index.html):

> The call of the onclick function is handled by x3dom by directly calling the callback function, since the addEventListener method needed to be overwritten. No page-wide onclick events are thrown, so attaching a listener to this object is only possible **after**.

I have not tested this but adding the onclick once in `componentDidMount` might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I was able to make it work by using 
`componentDidUpdate()`. I added an eventListner by giving `<shape>` some id. I also had to remove the eventListner to avoid a infinity loop. The problem with using `componentDidUpdate()` is that the component has to update somehow, before the method can be used. I did this by adding an extra state 'start' which i update from false to true after the first second when the application runs.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Toggle extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isToggleOn: true, start: false};

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); 
 }

 handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
    console.log("Pressed");
 }

 componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('Component update');

    //Have to do this to avoid potential infinty loop
    document.getElementById('someId').removeEventListener("click", this.handleClick);

    document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
 }

 render() {

    //Need to update component once, to run componentDidUpdate
    if(!(this.state.start)){
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({start: true });
        }, 1000)
    }
    //

    return (
        <div>
        <x3d width='500px' height='300px'>
            <scene>
                <shape id="someId">
                    <appearance>
                        <material id='color' diffusecolor={this.state.isToggleOn ? '1 0 0' : '0 0 1'}> </material>
                    </appearance>
                    <box></box>
                </shape>
            </scene>
        </x3d>
    </div>
    );  
  }
 }

ReactDOM.render(<Toggle />, document.getElementById('toggle'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for weeks, Thanks to the answers to your question, and to this non-related post : [Why does an onclick property set with setAttribute fail to work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/95731), i was able to make it work with `onClick` and `mouseover` events.

As said in one of the above answer, X3Dom comes with its own set of functions attached to the onClick event. And as mentioned in the X3DOM documentation, you can only attach your event after the document has loaded. Also @mistapink idea was correct except the `setAttribute`method does not work for some reasons. So I did that :

```
const Scene = () => {
   const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
   const handleMouseOver = () => {/* do some mouse over stuff here */};
const handleClick = () => setToggle(prevToggle => !prevToggle};
   useEffect(() => {
      const 3dObject = document.getElementById('my-3d-object'); 
/* I guess you can also try to use a reference, don't know if it'll work */
      document.onload = () => {
         3dObject.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
/* magic happens here  */
         3dObject.onclick = () => handleClick(
/* you can pass some extra arguments here */
);
      }
      return () => sphere.removeEvenetListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
    });

  return (...)
};
```