# Change onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, button, onclick

I have a button which redirects the user to the previous page:

```
<button id="back" onclick="location.href='..'">Back</button>
```

And I want to change his location to two pages before.

What's wrong with this code?

```
document.getElementById("back").setAttribute("onclick", function(){window.location.href='../../'});
```

or this

```
document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", "location.href='../../'");
```

or this

```
document.getElementById("back").onclick="location.href='../../'";
```

for some reason none of them work properly and my button remains unchanged... Google doesn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function(){
  window.location.href='../../';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```
<button id="back" onClick="GoBack()">Back</button>

<script>
   function GoBack(){
     window.location.href='../../';
   }
</script>
```

And If you want to go back to the previous page you can do like bellow

```
<button id="back" onClick="GoBack()">Back</button>

    <script>
       function GoBack(){
         window.history.go(-2);
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: I cannot change the original button because I need it into other pages

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better

```
document.querySelector("#back").addEventListener("click", () => window.history.go(-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `windows.history.go(-2);`:

```
<button onclick="windows.history.go(-2)">Back</button>
```

or save address of previous pages and reference to them.

Comment: I want to go two pages before in the url tree (es.`root/page1/page2/mypage`->go from `mypage` to `page1`), not backwards into the history

Comment: @Fox sorry. seems i didn't understand the question well:)

Answer (score 0):

1. `setAttribute` for `onclick` doesn't works in some browsers. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561099/12731030).
2. Syntax for `addEventListener` is

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);
```

Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

**So, Working code**

```
document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function(){
  window.location.href='../../';
});
```