# Why is this onclick button not working, in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am creating a calendar using JavaScript, HTML and CSS.
I got the code, but I want to do it when the date is clicked to show a modal.
I am a beginner in JavaScript.

What I want to do is when a element is clicked, I want to show a modal. I tried to test it out by changing the color, but it is not working.

```
function myFunction(elmnt,clr) {
  elmnt.style.color = clr;
}

td.setAttribute("onclick", "random(element, red)")
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
let today = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
let selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
let selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");

let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);


function next() {
    currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
    currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}



function jump() {
    currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
    currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}

function showCalendar(month, year) {

    let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
    let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();

    let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar

    // clearing all previous cells
    tbl.innerHTML = "";

    // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
    monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
    selectYear.value = year;
    selectMonth.value = month;

    // creating all cells
    let date = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
        for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode(" ");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                break;
            }

            else {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                    cell.classList.add("bg-info");
                } // color today's date
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                date++;
            }


        }

        tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
    }

}


function myFunction(elmnt,clr) {
  elmnt.style.color = clr;
}

td.setAttribute("onclick", "random(element, red)")
```

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendar</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container col-sm-4 col-md-7 col-lg-4 mt-5">
    <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header" id="monthAndYear"></h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sun</th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Thu</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="calendar-body">

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-inline">


            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-12" id="next" onclick="next()" width="200%">Next</button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <label class="lead mr-2 ml-2" for="month">Jump To: </label>
            <select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="month" id="month" onchange="jump()">
                <option value=0>Jan</option>
                <option value=1>Feb</option>
                <option value=2>Mar</option>
                <option value=3>Apr</option>
                <option value=4>May</option>
                <option value=5>Jun</option>
                <option value=6>Jul</option>
                <option value=7>Aug</option>
                <option value=8>Sep</option>
                <option value=9>Oct</option>
                <option value=10>Nov</option>
                <option value=11>Dec</option>
            </select>


            <label for="year"></label><select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="year" id="year" onchange="jump()">
            <option value=1990>1990</option>
            <option value=1991>1991</option>
            <option value=1992>1992</option>
            <option value=1993>1993</option>
            <option value=1994>1994</option>
            <option value=1995>1995</option>
            <option value=1996>1996</option>
            <option value=1997>1997</option>
            <option value=1998>1998</option>
            <option value=1999>1999</option>
            <option value=2000>2000</option>
            <option value=2001>2001</option>
            <option value=2002>2002</option>
            <option value=2003>2003</option>
            <option value=2004>2004</option>
            <option value=2005>2005</option>
            <option value=2006>2006</option>
            <option value=2007>2007</option>
            <option value=2008>2008</option>
            <option value=2009>2009</option>
            <option value=2010>2010</option>
            <option value=2011>2011</option>
            <option value=2012>2012</option>
            <option value=2013>2013</option>
            <option value=2014>2014</option>
            <option value=2015>2015</option>
            <option value=2016>2016</option>
            <option value=2017>2017</option>
            <option value=2018>2018</option>
            <option value=2019>2019</option>
            <option value=2020>2020</option>
            <option value=2021>2021</option>
            <option value=2022>2022</option>
            <option value=2023>2023</option>
            <option value=2024>2024</option>
            <option value=2025>2025</option>
            <option value=2026>2026</option>
            <option value=2027>2027</option>
            <option value=2028>2028</option>
            <option value=2029>2029</option>
            <option value=2030>2030</option>
        </select></form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<button name="jump" onclick="jump()">Go</button>-->
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Optional JavaScript for bootstrap -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? As far as I see, `td` is not defined in your code, which should throw a pretty clear error message in your browser's console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does an onclick property set with setAttribute fail to work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you scripts.js file you can replace the following code

```
function myFunction(elmnt,clr) {
  elmnt.style.color = clr;
}

td.setAttribute("onclick", "random(element, red)")
```

by

```
function random(elmnt,clr) {
  elmnt.style.color = clr;
}

document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(td) {
    td.setAttribute("onclick", "random(this, 'red')")
});
```

There were few mistakes in the code.

```
td.setAttribute("onclick", "random(element, red)")
```

1. td is not defined.
2. random is not defined
3. element is not defined
4. red is not defined

You can fix those by:
First select all the `td`s using the `document.querySelectorAll` function, then loop through the result. And then in the loop replace `random(element, red)` by `random(this, 'red')`. You see the `this` is a reference to the clicked td and `red` is wrapped in quotes.
And lastly you have to fix the function declaration. `function myFunction(elmnt,clr) {` to `function random(elmnt,clr) {`

Comment: Thansk, rly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

For your function to work you have to call it.
Instead of writing `random(element,red)` you should write `myFunction(element,red)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the onLoad function in the onload body attribute

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Code should be as below

```
function onLoad(){
   document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(){return false;}
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. **Why** should that be needed? Such constructs with inline-JS are pretty outdated