# How to get property js content edit it and run with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

im trying to use puppeteer to get property content of an element, edit it and run the edited version.
For example:
There is this element:

```
<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt58'),{'j_idt58:j_idt201:0:j_idt203':'j_idt58:j_idt201:0:j_idt203'},'_blank');return false" class="btn btn-info"></a>
```

What I need is to get the onclick content, remove the _blank parameter and run the rest of the function... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe not the most powerful solution out there but if you only need to do this on this specific tag you could set `onclick`'s attribute with JavaScript within `page.evalauate` like this:

```js
await page.evalauate(() => {
  document
    .querySelector(".btn.btn-info")
    .setAttribute(
      "onclick",
      document
        .querySelector(".btn.btn-info")
        .onclick.toString()
        .split("\n")[1]
        .replace(",'_blank'", "")
    );
});
await page.click(".btn.btn-info");
```

what's going on here?

1. we run plain JavaScript within the page's scope with [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate)
2. we select the tag with `document.querySelector`
3. and set its `onclick` [attribute (not its property!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95731/why-does-an-onclick-property-set-with-setattribute-fail-to-work-in-ie)
4. getting the node value of `onclick` as string:

```js
mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt58'),{'j_idt58:j_idt201:0:j_idt203':'j_idt58:j_idt201:0:j_idt203'},'_blank');return false
```

5. using the 2nd line of the function (as we don't need the 1st `'function onclick(event) {'` line when we reassign it as the attribute)
6. and replacing `,'_blank'` parameter from the original function (string).
7. the result will be:

```js
mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt58'),{'j_idt58:j_idt201:0:j_idt203':'j_idt58:j_idt201:0:j_idt203'});return false
```

8. finally clicking the button with `page.click` executes the new function

---

alternatively, you can use `attributes.onclick.nodeValue` if you are not comfortable with `toString().split("\n")[1]` above:

```js
document.querySelector(".btn.btn-info").attributes.onclick.nodeValue.replace(",'_blank'", "")
```

Comment: You saved the day. Thanks a lot for the explanation and the details. That solve the problem.